# I want to delete individual image in my albums controller in which I am inserting multiple images. How can I delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, rails-routing

I have set up the authentication using devise user, and in that I am having my albums controller in which i am inserting multiple images. So far I have just created a method for deletion of image in my albums controller.

My album controller looks like this:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    def index
        @albums = current_user.albums.all
    end
    def show 
        
        @album= current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    end 
    def new
        @album = current_user.albums.new
    end
    def create 
        @album = current_user.albums.new(album_params)
        if @album.save
            redirect_to albums_path 
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
    def edit
        @album =current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
        if @album.update(album_params)
            redirect_to albums_path
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
        @album.destroy 
        redirect_to albums_path
    end
    def delete_image_attachment
        @image = current_user.albums.ActiveStorage::Blob.find(params[:id])
        @image.purge
        redirect_to albums_path
    end
      
    
    private
        def album_params
            params.require(:album).permit(:title, :desciption,images: [])
        end
end
```

And you can see that I have created a method named `delete_image_attachment`..

Now I don't know what to enter in my routes file which is :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users 

  root to: "albums#index"
  resources :albums do 
    resources :comments
  end
  
end
```

And after giving route, what path can I give in my show page?

```
<%= link_to 'Remove',  ,method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are You Sure ?"} %>
```

My Rails routes are :

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#new
                            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                          devise/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                         devise/sessions#destroy
                       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                                     devise/passwords#new
                      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/passwords#edit
                           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#update
                                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                         devise/passwords#create
                cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                           devise/registrations#cancel
                   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                          devise/registrations#new
                  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                             devise/registrations#edit
                       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /users(.:format)                                                                                  devise/registrations#create
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 albums#index
                          album_comments GET    /albums/:album_id/comments(.:format)                                                              comments#index
                                         POST   /albums/:album_id/comments(.:format)                                                              comments#create
                       new_album_comment GET    /albums/:album_id/comments/new(.:format)                                                          comments#new
                      edit_album_comment GET    /albums/:album_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                                     comments#edit
                           album_comment GET    /albums/:album_id/comments/:id(.:format)                                                          comments#show
                                         PATCH  /albums/:album_id/comments/:id(.:format)                                                          comments#update
                                         PUT    /albums/:album_id/comments/:id(.:format)                                                          comments#update
                                         DELETE /albums/:album_id/comments/:id(.:format)                                                          comments#destroy
                                  albums GET    /albums(.:format)                                                                                 albums#index
                                         POST   /albums(.:format)                                                                                 albums#create
                               new_album GET    /albums/new(.:format)                                                                             albums#new
                              edit_album GET    /albums/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                        albums#edit
                                   album GET    /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                             albums#show
                                         PATCH  /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                             albums#update
                                         PUT    /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                             albums#update
                                         DELETE /albums/:id(.:format)                                                                             albums#destroy
           rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
              rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                              action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
           rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
     rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
           rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
            rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                                       action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
          rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                         POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
       new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
      edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
           rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                         PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_source GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources/new(.:format)                              rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#new
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_sources POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources(.:format)                                  rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#create
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                               rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                      rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
                rails_service_blob_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                  active_storage/blobs/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                        active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
               rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations/redirect#show
         rails_blob_representation_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)          active_storage/representations/redirect#show
                      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                                       active_storage/disk#show
               update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                               active_storage/disk#update
                    rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                                    active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Am I wrong in my method created for deleting image?

Comment: You should create a seperate controller (for example ImagesController) that handles CRUDing images instead of shoving everything into a single controller. Deleting an image should really be done with `DELETE /images/1` or `DELETE /albums/1/images/1`.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to CRUD images individually I would suggest you setup a intermediary model instead of using `has_many_attached :images` since its going to be pretty awkward to actually route to individal images.

This also gives you a logical place to annote images with stuff like captions. `has_many_attached` has its place but not if what you're attaching is actually a domain object.

```
resources :albums do
  resources :images, only: [:destroy]
end
```

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
end
```

```
module Image  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  has_one_attached :file
  # use callbacks to purge
end
```

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  before_action :set_image
  before_action :authorize_image

  # DELETE /albums/1/images/2
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    redirect_to @album, notice: 'Image removed'
  end

  private
  def set_image
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
  end

  # you should really consider using pundit or cancancan for authorization
  def authorize_image
    unless @album.user == current_user
      redirect_to root_path, error: "You're not authorized"
    end
  end
end
```

```
<% @album.images.each do |image| %>
  <div class="album-image">
    <%= image_tag image.file %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete image', [@album, image], method: :delete %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But i am  adding image on create album where i am having form of album model ... how will i be able to attach another model form there... coz submit will be different then?????  Are you getting ?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct?

```
@image = current_user.albums.ActiveStorage::Blob.find(params[:id])
```

I think we need to do

```
@image = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
```

and then

```
@image.purge
```

Comment: "I want to delete individual image in my albums controller in which i am inserting multiple images." - this won't acheive that. There is more extensive reworking/rethinking that needs to be done on the askers part.

Comment: `current_user.albums.ActiveStorage::Blob.find(params[:id])` will not work. Its not a method.